# Finding probability that an equation has real roots when two numbers are chosen from a uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, quadratics

The Question reads as follows:

Choose independently two numbers B and C at random from the interval [-1,1] with uniform distribution and consider the quadratic equation:

$$x^2+Bx+C=0$$

find the probability that the roots of this equation 
a) are both real
b) are both positive

I know a) requires that $0\le B^2-4C$ and b) requires $0\le B^2-4C$ , $B \le 0$ , $0 \le C$.

I know what this looks like geometrically and I believe for part a I should be able to integrate something from -1 to 1 but I am not sure what.

Comment: The probability that they're both real is the probability that $B^2 - 4C > 0.$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by knowing what it looks like geometrically. I would draw a picture showing the right areas in a $B$-$C$ plane. That would tell me what to integrate.

Comment: I know that the probability of $B^2-4C > 0$ is the probability that they are both real. I also did graph this so I know the bounds of the integral but I am not sure what function to integrate. I tried $\frac{-x^2}{4}$ but I got a negative answer which i know is not correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I believe I figured this out.

For A to be true we need the probability that $0 \le B^2-4C$. To find this I rearranged this to be $C \le \frac{B^2}{4}$ and this is the function we will integrate from -1 to 1.

$$ \int_{-1}^1 \frac{x^2}{4}dx = \frac{1}{6} \approx .1667$$

This would be the area under the curve but is not counting the rest of the area of our square. We must add this area to our integral and then divide by the total area of the square.

$\frac{1}{6} + 2 = \frac{13}{6}$

$\frac{\frac{13}{6}}{4} = \frac{13}{24}$

So this is the probability that the roots of the equation are real.

Looking at the constraints on part B we can see that we have more constraints. This will change the bounds of our integral.

$$ \int_{-1}^0 \frac{x^2}{4}dx = \frac{1}{12} \approx .08333 $$

Here we do not need to add back in any area because given our constraints this is the only section we are looking for. We still must divide by the total area of the square though.

$\frac{\frac{1}{12}}{4} = \frac{1}{48}$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{{\Huge\left. a\right)}}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{-1}^{1}{1 \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}{1 \over 2}\bracks{B^{2} - 4C \geq 0}
\,\dd B\,\dd C =
{1 \over 4}\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\bracks{C \leq {B^{2} \over 4}}
\,\dd C\,\dd B
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 4}\int_{-1}^{1}\braces{%
\bracks{{B^{2} \over 4} < 1}\int_{-1}^{B^{2}/4}\,\dd C +
\bracks{{B^{2} \over 4} > 1}\int_{-1}^{1}\,\dd C}\dd B
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 4}\int_{-1}^{1}\braces{%
\bracks{B^{2} < 4}\pars{{B^{2} \over 4} + 1} + \bracks{B^{2} > 4}2}\dd B =
{1 \over 4}\,2\int_{0}^{1}\pars{{B^{2} \over 4} + 1}\dd B
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\pars{{1 \over 12}\,B^{3} + B}_{0}^{1} = {1 \over 2}\pars{{1 \over 12} + 1} = \bbx{13 \over 24} \approx 0.5417
\end{align}

---

$\ds{{\Huge\left. b\right)}}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{-1}^{1}{1 \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}{1 \over 2}\bracks{B^{2} - 4C \geq 0}
\bracks{B \leq 0}\bracks{0 \leq C}\,\dd B\,\dd C =
{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{-1}^{0}\bracks{C \leq {B^{2} \over 4}}
\,\dd C\,\dd B
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{1}\,\dd B = \bbx{1 \over 4} = 0.25
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The chart shows the sample space of all randomly chosen points (B, C), where B and C are drawn from the interval [-1,1] with uniform distribution.

Added is the line $B^2 = 4C$. Any point right of the line will not be a real root as $B^2 - 4C < 0$.

[image]

The probability of getting real roots is:

$$ \frac{\text{area left of line}}{\text{total area}}$$

- The `total area` is 4 (2 x 2).
- The area right of the blue line is 1.5 (0.75 x 2)
- The area under the curve (from 0 to 0.25) is given by:

$$ \int_{0}^{0.25} 2\sqrt{c}\text{ dx} = \left[\frac{4}{3} x^\frac{3}{2}\right]_0^{0.25} \approx 0.16667$$

*Note: $B^2 = 4C$ is re-written as $B = 2\sqrt{C}$*

With the above we have:

$$ \frac{\text{area left of line}}{\text{total area}} = \frac{4 - \text{(1.5 + 2 x 0.16667)}}{4} \approx {0.541667} \approx \frac{13}{24}$$